# Tor doesn't load any webpages same with the firefox

Tags: tor-install, troubleshooting

I'm running Windows 7 system with 2 GB DDR and Intel Celeron D 335 and Nvidia Geforce FX 5500.

When I run Tor (or any similar firefox based browser) it show me an empty page; also It can't load anypages.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You might get more help somewhere like the SuperUser stack exchange, or the official Firefox bug tracker. My advice would be to get Firefox working first, and then Tor Browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply